# excluding files with guard-jasmine while running coverage

Tags: jasmine, guard

I am using guard-jasmine create coverage reports for my javascript app written with backbone js. I would like to exclude the template files from being included in the coverage. Is there a way to do this currently? I have also tried looking through the source and passing the -x option to the intrument command in the coverage.rb file but that doesn't seem to help at all. Any pointers would be appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is currently no way of configuring Guard::Jasmine to skip specific files from generating the coverage.

A possible way to add this would be to add something like a `coverage_skip` option that contains a regex to check it as a preconodition in the [coverage tilt template](https://github.com/netzpirat/guard-jasmine/blob/master/lib/guard/jasmine/coverage.rb#L19-L20):

```
return data if file =~ ENV['COVERAGE_SKIP']
```

Since we do not have access to the Guard::Jasmine options, [we need to set it as an environment](https://github.com/netzpirat/guard-jasmine/blob/master/lib/guard/jasmine/server.rb#L100) variable in the server process.

A pull  request is heartly welcome ;)

Comment: Thanks! I will submit a pull request